# How to get the number of commit per a year for github-api

Tags: github

I would like to know the number of commit per user-account in a year.

github provides the following api.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/commit_activity
```

But what I want is not the number of commit in the repository.

I think i can add after getting the number of commit for all the repository, but I think it's very inefficient.(Also, if the number of repertoires is large, unnecessary `GET request` is increased.)

Can I know the number of commit per a year for all the repositories of an user-account at just a one `GET` request?

Comment: What about `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:USERNAME` or similar?

Comment: That wouldn't work if the caller doesn't have permission to view one or more private repositories that the user has committed to.  And for that reason, I doubt that there's a solution to this question.